# What does "Co-op Partner Locator" do in Dead Space 3?

Tags: dead-space-3

I recently got the game (thank you humble bundle), and I was going through the settings and this caught my eye:

[image: dead space 3 co-op partner locator]

Question is, what is it? What does it do? On the main page it has an option to create a co-op game already, so why do I have a separate option to enable a "Co-op Partner Locator"?

Comment: This option allows you to locate your partner on the map. Kind of like Halo where there is an arrow right on top of the player's head

Comment: Seems like an answer. Put it down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what it says on the Tin.

Allows you to locate your co-op partner.